# Why can't I find the servers I created using MySQL Workbench on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0

I created two servers on MySQL Workbench in hopes that I would be able to connect to said server using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and create an SQL Server Database (.mdf) which I would then use to create a desktop application using C#.

I tried searching all over the net but nothing helps me. Also, I think my Visual C# Express 2010 does not support connecting MySQL Database instances, lest importing it to the application for I would publish the application later on.

I was trying to find an alternative database that I can use instead of Access databases since I heard it accumulates more space as more data is entered into it. So, I tried SQL Server databases but just creating one is leading me to these problems

Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are completely separate. Use Workbench to connect to MySQL and Management Studio to connect to SQL Server (mdf) databases.

Comment: But the problem is, I can't create a server on Management Studio

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe: why would you expect to be able to create a MySQL "server" (I presume you mean instance here) from Microsoft's tool for SQL Server?

Comment: probably because you did not install SQL Server Engine. SSMS is just a tool to "MANAGE" server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a SQL Server database (.mdf, manageable using SQL Server Management Studio), you have to install Microsoft SQL Server on the computer the database will run on.

SQL Server consists of more than just the Management studio.  You have to install the server components to host a database - If all you have is the management studio, you can only connect to databases hosted on other computers.

After SQL Server is installed, you can connect to it using management studio and create your database once connected.

If you're concerned about cost, Microsoft offers SQL Server Express as a free edition of SQL Server with a few limitations.